# Sequelize: When querying data I want to accumulate a specific field in a nested array of objects on the top level of the returned instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Sequelize 6.0:

I am using `findOne` on my User model and including `Roles` and `Permissions` (they're nested).

The resulting user instance looks (something) like this:

```
{
  "id": "ID",
  "username": "user1",
  "email": "user@user.com",
  "firstName": "User",
  "lastName": "Last",
  "role": "USER",
  "spotifyId": "fakespotifyid10",
  "createdAt": "2020-05-19T17:56:26.992Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-19T17:56:26.992Z",
  "Role": {
    "name": "USER",
    "Permissions": [
      {
        "name": "createUser"
      },
      {
        "name": "getUser"
      },
      {
        "name": "updateUser"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

While this is fine, it would be nice if I could accumulate all the permission names in a top level field named `permissions`.  I believe there's a way to do this but I'm having trouble.

What I'd like the returned user instance to look like:

```
{
  "id": "ID",
  "username": "user1",
  "email": "user@user.com",
  "firstName": "User",
  "lastName": "Last",
  "role": "USER",
  "spotifyId": "fakespotifyid10",
  "createdAt": "2020-05-19T17:56:26.992Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-19T17:56:26.992Z",
  "permissions": ['getUser', 'updateUser', 'createUser']
}
```

Here is the query for reference:

```
const findUserByEmailWithPermissions = email =>
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email,
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: Role,
        attributes: ['name'],
        include: [
          {
            model: Permission,
            attributes: ['name'],
            through: {
              attributes: [],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  })
```

**Edit**:
Here are the relevant associations:

```
User.belongsTo(Role, { foreignKey: { name: 'role', allowNull: false } })

Role.belongsToMany(Permission, {
  through: RolePermission,
  foreignKey: { name: 'roleName', allowNull: false },
})
```

Comment: show model definitions and associations

Comment: It should be possible to have `permissions` be a virtual field that transforms the `Roles` attribute to the desired format. See https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getters-setters-virtuals.html#virtual-fields
The `Roles` field would still be there but maybe that's ok.

Comment: @Christian This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.